# Fail to get Set-Cookie response header angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

My localhost application is calling a rest web service with `POST` Method.
 (It's a remote web service not at localhost).

As headers response , i got only these:

```
pragma: "no-cache", content-type: "application/json", cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", expires: "0".
```

I want to get the `set-cookie` header to use it to call another web service.

In the chrome developer tools, the cookie is set as `httpOnly` that's why i'm not able to get it in the frontend part.

Is there any solution for this?